# AngularJS ngClick to fire a service but doesn't

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following inside a directive

```
scope.actions = {
    getSearch: searchResultPageService.getSearch(scope.keywords, scope.settings)
};
```

The template is as follows

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-ng-click="actions.getSearch()">Send</button>
```

In my service I'm only checking to see if the `scope.keywords` and `scope.settings` are passed through using a console.log but there is no output.

what am I doing wrong with my ngClick usage

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.search')
        .factory('searchResultPageService', [
            '$timeout',
            function ($timeout) {
                var $module = {

                    getSearch: function(keywords, settings){
                        console.log(keywords);
                        console.log(settings);
```

Comment: You are just affecting searchResultPageService.getSearch(scope.keywords, scope.settings) result to actions.getSearch. This is not a method, excepted if searchResultPageService.getSearch(scope.keywords, scope.settings) return a method - I've a little doubt -.

You just have to try this:

scope.actions = {
    getSearch: function() { searchResultPageService.getSearch(scope.keywords, scope.settings) });
};

Answer (score 2):

`scope.actions.getSearch` is the result returned from calling `searchResultPageService.getSearch`, rather than the function itself.

You either need to pass the reference to that function to the view:

```
scope.actions = {
    getSearch: searchResultPageService.getSearch
};
```

And modify your view's click handler as follows:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-ng-click="actions.getSearch(keywords, settings)">Send</button>
```

**Or** create a new anonymous function which is sent to the view:

```
scope.actions = {
    getSearch: function() {
        searchResultPageService.getSearch(scope.keywords, scope.settings);
    }
};
```

In which case your view code stays the same. Personally I would choose the second option there.

Comment: I see what you've done here, but when unit testing comes it would be easier to declare the anon function in the service?

Comment: @Donald Not according to your requirement. The assertion for the anonymous function here would be that `getSearch` is called with the expected `scope.keywords` and `scope.settings` values. This would be part of your controller tests. `searchResultPageService.getSearch` would be tested separately as part of your service tests.

Answer (score 0):

You are just affecting

```
searchResultPageService.getSearch(scope.keywords, scope.settings)
```

result to

```
actions.getSearch
```

This is not a method, excepted if

```
searchResultPageService.getSearch(scope.keywords, scope.settings)
```

return a method - I've a little doubt -

Just try :

```
scope.actions = {
  getSearch: function() {
    searchResultPageService.getSearch(scope.keywords, scope.settings);
  }
};
```